# Confusion over the dilation property of Lebesgue Integrals

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

I have seen that (for the Lebesgue integral) the dilation invariance property is stated:

$\delta^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(\delta x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x) dx$,

but this seems counter intuitive (of course, my intuition is wrong, but let's continue). I would have believed that it would instead be the case that:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(\delta x) dx = \delta^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x) dx$.

I decided to try and prove it for myself with the case $f(x) = \chi_E (x)$. Here is my proof:

Let $f(x) = \chi_E(x)$.

Then $f(\delta x) = \chi_E(\delta x) = \chi_{\delta E} (x)$ where $\delta E = \{ \delta x : x \in E \}$.

Recall that $m(\delta E) = \delta^d m(E)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

So we can write:

$\begin{gather}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(\delta x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \chi_E (\delta x) dx \\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \chi_{\delta E} (x) dx \\
=m(\delta E) \\
=\delta^d m(E) \\
=\delta^d\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \chi_E (x) dx \\
=\delta^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) dx.
\end{gather}$

Which was my intuition and $\textbf{not}$ the actual true statement. This leads me to believe that my proof is wrong somewhere. Let me know where.

Comment: Second line: $\delta x$ is in E if $x$ is in $E/\delta$. In general this property is just the same as u substitution: when you substitute $u=\delta x$, replacing $dx$ by $du$ requires multiplication by "$dx/du$" in the transformed integral.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what is wrong there. The definition $\delta E = \{ \delta x : x \in E \}$ is given in my book (Stein, Real Analysis).

Comment: $\delta x \in \delta E$ iff $x \in E$, so $\delta x \in E$ iff $x \in \delta^{-1} E$.

Comment: Look at a small example: $C\int_0^\infty e^{-2x} dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x} dx$. $C$ is definitely $2$, not $1/2$, because the coefficient of $2$ causes faster decay.

Comment: That is an instructive example- I appreciate if for building my intuition. Also, given the comment of $\delta x \in E$ iff $ x \in \delta^{-1} E$ we would have $\delta^d \mapsto \delta^{-d}$ and the proof is complete. I may try and answer my own question now, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct proof goes like:

Let $f(x) = \chi_E(x)$.

$\textbf{Note that $x \in E$ iff $\delta x \in \delta E$. Therefore $\delta x \in E$ iff  $x \in \delta^{-1} E$.}$

Then $f(\delta x) = \chi_E(\delta x) = \chi_{\delta^{-1} E} (x)$ where $\delta E = \{ \delta x : x \in E \}$.

Recall that $m(\delta E) = \delta^d m(E)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

So we can write:

$\begin{gather}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(\delta x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \chi_E (\delta x) dx \\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \chi_{\delta^{-1} E} (x) dx \\
=m(\delta^{-1} E) \\
=\delta^{-d} m(E) \\
=\delta^{-d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \chi_E (x) dx \\
=\delta^{-d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) dx.
\end{gather}$

Which is the correct result.